# Protobuf-net with ServiceStack and compact framework

Tags: compact-framework, servicestack, protobuf-net

I wrote a server that uses servicestack, and a client that connects to it using both JSON and protobuf-net (so I'm sure the server works...).
Now I need to develop the same client on Windows Mobile with CF3.5, and since servicestack is not supported on CF3.5 I used on the client HttpWebRequest and NewtonSoft.Json.Compact for the json part, this way:

Classes:

```
[ProtoContract]
public class ReqPing 
{
}

[ProtoContract]
public class RespPing
{
    [ProtoMember(1)]
    public string Result { get; set; }
}
```

Function:

```
ReqPing iReqPing = new ReqPing();

string json = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(iReqPing);

HttpWebRequest req = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create("http://192.168.0.87:82/json/syncreply/ReqPing");
req.ContentType = "text/json";
req.Method = "POST";
req.ContentLength = json.Length;

            using (var streamWriter = new StreamWriter(req.GetRequestStream()))
            {
                streamWriter.Write(json);
                streamWriter.Flush();
                streamWriter.Close();
            }

            HttpWebResponse resp = (HttpWebResponse)req.GetResponse();

            Stream respStream = resp.GetResponseStream();

            string resps;

            using (var reader = new StreamReader(respStream, Encoding.UTF8))
            {
                resps = reader.ReadToEnd();                
            }

            respStream.Close();

            JsonTextReader jreader = new JsonTextReader(new StringReader(resps));
            JsonSerializer serializer = new JsonSerializer();
            RespPing iRespPing = serializer.Deserialize<RespPing>(jreader);
```

and it works, so now I'm trying to implement the same with protobuf, and I'm stuck here:

```
ReqPing iReqPing = new ReqPing();


var ms = new MemoryStream();?????? correct way?

Serializer.Serialize<ReqPing>(ms, iReqPing);

HttpWebRequest req = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create("http://192.168.0.87:82/x-protobuf/reply/ReqPing");
            req.ContentType = "application/x-protobuf";
            req.Method = "POST";
            req.ContentLength = ????????

how can I write the serialized stream to req??               

            HttpWebResponse resp = (HttpWebResponse)req.GetResponse();

            Stream respStream = resp.GetResponseStream();

            RespPing iRespPing = Serializer.Deserialize<RespPing>(respStream);
```

Anyone can suggest me what's the right way?

Thanks!
Mattia

EDIT:

Ok on how to use the stream, but I need to set ContentLength too, or I get an error message on GetRequestStream (saying that I must set ContentLength...).
I made it work with:

```
byte[] data;
        using(var stream = new MemoryStream()) 
        {
            Serializer.Serialize(stream, iReqPing);
            data = stream.ToArray();
            req.ContentLength = data.Length;
        }

        using(var stream = req.GetRequestStream()) 
        {
            stream.Write(data, 0, data.Length);                
        }
```

Is there another obvious way I'm missing?

Another question: 
I made it work but after two request, at the third it timeouts in GetRequestStream. I noticed I forgot in my previous call to make a call to Close() in my HttpWebResponse, I corrected it and now works.
The strange thing is that I forgot to close HttpWebResponse even with my JSON version,and there I had no problems...the routine is exactly the same.. can you guess the reason?
Thanks again!

Comment: I'm confused - you're talking about serialization but calling deserialize. Are you trying to read here? Or write?

Comment: iReqPing is my request, and I suppose that I must Serialize it to send it with HttpWebRequest.
After that, I get the response stream and try to deserialize it in my iRespPing response object.

I trying to follow the same schema I used for the previous JSON example, bu want to serialize with protobuf instead of JSON.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> how can I write the serialized stream to req??

```
using(var stream = req.GetRequestStream()) {
    Serializer.Serialize(stream, iReqPing);
}
```

and then to deserialize, as you already have correctly:

```
RespPing iRespPing;
using(var stream = resp.GetResponseStream()) {
    iRespPing = Serializer.Deserialize<RespPing>(respStream);
}
```

No need for a `MemoryStream` unless you specifically want to sent the length manually. If you *do* want to buffer, then maybe:

```
byte[] data;
using(var stream = new MemoryStream()) {
    Serializer.Serialize(stream, iReqPing);
    data = stream.ToArray();
}
...
using(var stream = req.GetRequestStream()) {
    stream.Write(data, 0, data.Length);
}
```

---

Edit to show more efficient use of `MemoryStream` re the now-edited question:

```
    byte[] data;
    int len;
    using(var stream = new MemoryStream()) 
    {
        Serializer.Serialize(stream, iReqPing);
        data = stream.GetBuffer(); // note this is oversized!
        len = (int)stream.Length;
    }
    req.ContentLength = len;

    using(var stream = req.GetRequestStream()) 
    {
        stream.Write(data, 0, len); 
    }
```

The subtlety here is that we have avoided having to duplicate the `MemoryStream`'s buffer - instead we obtain the **oversized** back-buffer (remembering to note how much of it is actually data), and then write *just that many* bytes. So `data.Length` could be (as an example) `4096`, but `len` could be `3012`. This avoids an extra `byte[]` allocation and a `Buffer.BlockCopy`.

Comment: sorry! I'm quite sure I wrote the entire comment...I wonder what happened. I edited the Question now, thanks!

Comment: @MattiaDurli re your edit - yep, that looks about right; you *can* make it slightly more efficient - I'll edit to demonstrate